# why the second for syntax is not allowed?

Tags: c

```
for ( declaration expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
```

This second syntax of for loop is only with one semicolon but whenever I try to use it, it generates an error saying that:

```
error: expected `;` before `)` token
```

Comment: Its `for (init; condition; iteration)`, you have one parameter missing that's why it "expected a ; before )"

Comment: Here is what the standards says it gives **two** syntax: `for ( expressionopt ; expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement`
`for ( declaration expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
`

Comment: @Sabrina I don't know what standard that is, but surely isn't C's.

Comment: Yes exactly I did not notice that thanks Alexander.

Comment: @Havenard: It is the C11 (or C99) standard — both allow the C++-like `for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)` loop notation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C11 standard specifies two forms for the `for` loop (§6.8.5 Iteration statements):

> - `for` `(` *expression<sub>opt</sub>* `;` *expression<sub>opt</sub>* `;` *expression<sub>opt</sub>* `)` *statement*
> - `for` `(` *declaration* *expression<sub>opt</sub>* `;` expression<sub>opt</sub>_ `)` *statement*

The rule for '*declaration*' ends with a semicolon, so there must be two semicolons in the control section of a `for` loop.

> §6.7 **Declarations**
>
> *declaration:*
>     *declaration-specifiers* *init-declarator-list<sub>opt</sub>* `;`
>     *static_assert-declaration*